# Compiler cannot see base class

Tags: c++, compilation

I have code like the following:

```
#include "c:\code\CodeHeaders\Baseclass.hpp"  // include full path out of desperation

class ChildClass: public BaseClass
{
   // awesome code which breaks the laws of physics
}
```

However, I get the compiler error:

error C2504: 'BaseClass' : base class undefined

Even though I have confirmed it is in the header file which is included.  The list of included files provided by the compiler contains this header file so it I cannot see why it does not see the definition of the base class.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is it in the same namespace?

Comment: Could you also share the Baseclass.hpp file?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the class declaration...

Comment: DOH!!!!!  There was a macro that got removed which contained a namespace usage command!!!!!  @KirilKirov, if you make your comment an answer I will accept it and have to tolerate looking like a fool! :-)

Comment: @Stefan - ready. I'm glad that I helped. Don't worry, such errors happen very often, including to experienced developers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>"Moving" my comment as answer, as it looks like it helped solving the issue.</sub>

This is most probably caused by some `namespace` mismatch or something similar. You should check `Baseclass.hpp` for this.

Comment: Yep - in case someone else gets this and wants to avoid making a complete fool of themselves then check the #defines to make sure that they do not contain namespace declarations!

Answer (score 2):

You use `#include` the wrong way.

First of all, do not use **backslashes** (`\`)  even if you're on Windows. Always use forward slashes (`/`)!

Second, do not specify **absolute filesystem paths**.

Specify relative paths if the file belongs to the same project as the including file (notice that the word "project" does not have a strict technical definition in C++ itself, so when I say "project" I more or less mean "if the files belong together" for the same program or the same bigger component).

Example:

```
#include "BaseClass.hpp"
```

Or:

```
#include "../BaseClass.hpp"
```

Or:

```
#include "../CodeHeaders/BaseClass.hpp"
```

Specify absolute paths if the included file belongs to a **library** you want to use. In this case, you include the file with `< >`:

Example:

```
#include <BaseClass.hpp>
```

Or:

```
#include <CodeHeaders/BaseClass.hpp>
```

Notice how this is similar to using standard headers like `<vector>` or `<iostream>`.

The difficulty in this case is to tell your building environment where the compiler can find such library include files. How this is done entirely depends on your compiler. For example, if you are using MSVC, use the [`/I` compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx).

Example:

```
cl /Ic:\CodeHeaders ChildClass.cpp
```

Using libraries correctly is an important step in learning how to master C++.

Comment: Fair points, the only reason I included the full path of the include was to make it ear it was not a directory offset problem! :-)